# Compactness proof in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that if $K \subset  \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and all continuous functions  whose domain is $K$  are bounded then $K$ is compact?

I feel we should use the extreme value theorem but I don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to prove that $K$ is closed and bounded. Now consider these:

- If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is unbounded, then $x \mapsto \|x\|$ is a continuous unbounded function on $X$.
- If $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is not closed, and $x_0 \in \bar X \setminus X$, then $x \mapsto \frac1{\|x-x_0\|}$ is a continuous unbounded function on $X$.